# Energy Equality: how to derive the energy equalities?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Sorry! I'm wondering if there is some way of deriving the energy equality of a given equation.
If possible, I would like to see a specific example, which is
$ u_ {tt}- \Delta u + u^3 = 0 $ ($ u $ is equal to $0$ in the boundary).
(I guess it's in $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2 $)
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to this site! it might help if you described what exactly yom mean by the "energy equality".

Comment: Do you mean the energy functional?

Comment: yes, @Shuhao Cao